# Seeming abitrariness of the Maximum Entropy Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

I have a two parameter model $C = (C_1, C_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and would like to look at the choice of parameters from a stochastic point of view. A minimal set of constraints on $C$ is that

1. The mean $\underline{C} = (\underline{C_1},\underline{C_2})$ is known, which can be written as $\mathbb{E}(C) = \underline{C}$;
2. $\mathbb{E}\{g(C)\} = \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is finite and $G(C) = \log(C_1 C_2^{-3})$ (note that the choice of $\alpha$ is up to me, the point here is merely that it is finite, which is important given the $\log$ here);
3. The normalisation constraint, which can be written as $\mathbb{E}\{1\} = 1$.

All three constraints can be written in the form of mathematical expactations, namely $\mathbb{E}\{F(C)\} = H$, where $F\,\colon\, \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ with $F(C) = (C,g(C),1)$ and $H = (\underline{C},\alpha,1) \in \mathbb{R}^4$,

In my naive understanding of the Maximum Entropy Principle, as discussed in the classical paper Information theory and statistical mechanics by ‎Jaynes it seems that in this case the maximum entropy p.d.f. of the random variable $C$ is given by
$$
\rho_C(c) = \mathbb{1}_{\mathcal{S}}(c) \exp\{-\langle \lambda,\,F(c) \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^4}\} = \mathbb{1}_{\mathcal{S}}(c)\,k_4\,\exp\{-\lambda_1 c_1\} \exp\{-\lambda_2 c_2\} c_1^{-\lambda_3}c_2^{3\lambda_3}
$$
where $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_4)$ is the set of Lagrange multipliers corresponding to constraints and $\mathcal{S}$ is the largest set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which the constraints are satisfied. Clearly from constraint 2. we have $C_1 > 0$ and $C_2 > 0$ so $\mathcal{S} = \mathbb{R}_+^2$. Note that $k_4 = \exp\{-\lambda_4\}$ is the normalisation constant.

One can see that in fact
$$
\rho_C(c) = \rho_{C_1}(c_1) \times \rho_{C_2}(c_2)
$$
and both $C_1$ and $C_2$ follow Gamma distribution, with hyperparameters (shape and scale):
$$
(\alpha_1,\beta_1) = (1-\lambda_3,\underline{c_1}/(1-\lambda_3)) \quad\text{ and }\quad (\alpha_2,\beta_2) = (1+3\lambda_3,\underline{c_2}/(1+3\lambda_3)).
$$
This is where my confusion starts. The parameter $\lambda_3$ is a sense free since as mentioned $\alpha$ in constaint 2. can vary and also $\lambda_3$ is joint for both random variables, and for both of them to be Gamma distributed it needs to satisfy $\lambda_3 \in (-1/3,1)$, as otherwise the integral of the density is not integrable near zero. But this severely limits our control of "statistical fluctuations", since a large negative $\lambda_3$ would mean the density $\rho_{C_1}$ strongly concentrated near the mean $\underline{c_1}$. There seem to be two ways of working with this.

(1) We persist with the current setup and e.g. if it is necessary to set $\lambda_3 = -100$, then presumably $C_2$ is not Gamma distributed and we have to exlude the origin and say that the support of $\rho_{C_2}$ is $(\epsilon,+\infty)$ but how does one choose $\epsilon$ here? It seems like any $\epsilon$ would do, which seems a bit nonsensical given the broader context.

(2) We can also resort to a change of variables to $B = (B_1,B_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $B_1 = C_1$ but $B_2 = C_2^{-1}$. Clearly there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\underline{C} \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$ and $\underline{B} \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$ and in the second constaint $G$ is replaced by $\tilde{G}(B) = \log(B_1B_2^3)$. If we use the same framework as above, the conclusion appears to be that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are both Gamma-distributed, this time with hyperparameters
$$
(\alpha_1,\beta_1) = (1-\lambda_3,\underline{b_1}/(1-\lambda_3)) \quad\text{ and }\quad (\alpha_2,\beta_2) = (1-3\lambda_3,\underline{b_2}/(1+3\lambda_3)),
$$
so now $\lambda_3 \in (-\infty,1/3)$ and we have the freedom to set $\lambda_3$ as negative as we like, so we can control the 'scale' of the relevant oscillations around the mean.

What strikes me here is the seeming arbtrariness of the maximum entropy principle in this case: in the alternative approach (2) we arrive at the conclusion that $B_2$ is Gamma distrubuted, so that would mean that $C_2 = B_2^{-1}$ follows 'Inverse Gamma distribution'. In the original setup $C_2$ follows Gamma distribution on the other hand. So which is it?

I suppose it all relies on the fact that in general in both settings $\lambda_3$ is not really constrained to lie in an interval, but rather that if $\lambda_3$ is within the intervals stated, then the the underlying random variables are indeed Gamma-distributed. If that is the case then I suppose the alternative approach (2) is the way to go, as it gives a nicer picture at the end. I would appreciate any comments people might have, thank you for going through this wall of text :)

Comment: A couple of points - it isn't known that $c_1 > 0, c_2 > 0$, since the constraint is on $\log \frac{c_1}{c_2^3}$ - so it perfectly fine to have mass on  the region $\{c_1 <0, c_2 < 0\}$. This also introduces a (weak) dependence between $C_1$ and $C_2$, which is that their sign must agree. Further, it isn't clear to me that $\alpha$ is completely free - it is quite plausible that the means of $C_1$ and $C_2$ impose some condition on the possible means of $\log(C_1/C_2^3)$. As for your paragraph (2), aren't you constraining the mean of $1/C_2$ in this case, and thus getting a different law?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting! I can see that my wording is quite sloppy, I apologise. Indeed it should added on top of the listed constraints that in my model only positive $C_1$ and $C_2$ make sense, so this would be a yet another constraint.

I also agree that $\alpha$ may not necessarily be completely free. It could well be that in fact $\alpha$ can only be such that $\lambda_3$ is within the interacl I stated (I will look at the underlying computation closely). 

I will comment on your final point in a separate comment due to the character limit.

Comment: No worries. I also wanted to point out that the inverse gamma needs both the parameters to be positive, which imposes further constraints such as $\underline{b_2}(1+3\lambda_3) > 0 \implies \lambda_3 > -1/3.$ Further, I guess one may handle the ambiguity to an extent by the relation between $\mathrm{Inv}\mathrm{Inv}\Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ laws in the sense that for some set of parameters of the $\mathrm{Inv}\Gamma,$ clearly the inverse of a random variable distributed this way is $\Gamma$ - is it the case that the allowed $\lambda_3$ are all in (contd)

Comment: such a domain? If so, then the set of joint laws you're able to express as $\Gamma$ or as $\mathrm{Inv}\Gamma$ are the same and there's no arbitrariness.

Comment: Yes you are correct with regards to what happens in (2). However, I think the main point of my confusion is that to my untrained eye these constraints are very similar. In my model $C_1$ and $C_2$ have typical values, which I take as a mean. Putting stochasticity aside, swapping $C_1,C_2$ for $B_1, B_2$ does not really change anything, now the typical value is $B_2 = C_2^{-1}$. I can by that stage forget about $C_1,C_2$ altogether and have a constaint $\mathbb{E}(B_2) = \underline{B_2}$.

Comment: So really my question here I think is: why would one say that one set of constraints is more reasonable than the other? Changing to $B_1,B_2$ just seems more convenient - can I just do it out of convenience?

Comment: Of course you can, but remember that these are always balancing acts. For the situation that you're modeling, is it natural to impose constraints on the mean of $1/C_2$ (remember e.g. that the mean of the inverse can be quite different from the inverse of the mean) ?  If not, does the more convenient form of the expression buy you enough to justify doing this? These are all context dependent things, but you can most certainly choose to do things in the way most convenient for you.

Comment: One final comment is that your last paragraph is important too - basically $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are not even constrained to be negative, so it's possible that the laws aren't Gamma anyway - one case where this would happen is if you had constrained $\mathbb{E}[\log C_1] = \log \mathbb{E}[C_1]$ which would force $C_1$ to be a point mass due to strong concavity of the $\log$. Such things could well be important for the situation you're modeling. (On the whole the situation seems complicated to me, which is why I'm writing comments and not an answer :) )

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, they are very helpful!